# Place text values one below the other in different paragraph

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-4 order">
    <a class="aremove" href="/Channel/Details/273">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../../Images/img/channelimages/imgB2B.png">
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="channel-stats-heading">
                    <b>B2BChannel</b>
                </p>
                <p class="color-grey">
                    <span>0</span> out of stock
                </p>
                <p class="color-grey">
                    <b>20</b> pending process
                </p>
                <p class="color-grey">
                    <span>1</span> this month
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

How do place the numbers one below the other in CSS?

[image]

Comment: Your example **is** displaying one below the other? Are you wanting to center align them? I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: What's the current CSS that produces the output you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the minimal Information you provide, I'm interpreting the question as "how do I centre the paragraphs, while aligning the numbers each above, or below, the others?" To which I suggest:

```
div.caption {
  /* to approximate the design you show in the picture,
     adjust to taste, irrelevant to the result: */
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
p.color-grey {
  /* to approximately-center the content: */
  margin-left: 40%;
  width: 50%;

  /* to allow for absolute positioning of the :first-child
     in relation to its parent: */
  position: relative;
}
p.color-grey >:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;

  /* to position the :first-child outside of the
     parent element, with the right-edge aligned: */
  right: 102%;

  /* to provide space between the number of the
     aligned element and the text of the parent
     element: */         
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}
```

```css
div.caption {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
p.color-grey {
  margin-left: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
p.color-grey >:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 102%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <p class="color-grey"><span>0</span> out of stock</p>
  <p class="color-grey"><b>20</b> pending process</p>
  <p class="color-grey"><span>1</span> this month</p>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sy00f975/) for experimentation and development.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a float to your span and b elements.

```
p.color-grey span, p.color-grey b {
   float: left;
}
```

And to center the text inside the span and b you can add some width to it.

Here is the bin : [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nuyoxehafe/edit?html,css,js,output)

I assume that's what you've needed.

Comment: `<span>` and `<b>` elements are inline, why would you float them?

Comment: @Aaron well, the actually are. But in that case float helps.